# what the meaning of "borrowed data escapes outside of closure reference escapes the closure body here" for the following code?

Tags: rust

```
pub fn restore_string(s: String, indices: Vec<i32>) -> String {
    let mut res_arr_str = vec![""; s.len()]; // 1
    let mut res_arr_char = vec![' '; s.len()]; //2
    let mut res_arr_string = vec!["".to_string(); s.len()]; // 3
    s.char_indices().for_each(move |(index, ch)| {
        res_arr_str[indices[index] as usize] = &ch.to_string();
        res_arr_char[indices[index] as usize] = ch;
        res_arr_string[indices[index] as usize] = ch.to_string();
    });
    res_arr_char.into_iter().collect()
}
```

i do not understand why 1 is error,but 2 and 3 not,which basic knowlodge i have not understand,which concept

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get.

Comment: ```
let mut res_arr_str: Vec<&str>
Go to Vec | Global

borrowed data escapes outside of closure
reference escapes the closure body hererustcE0521
main.rs(297, 9): `res_arr_str` declared here, outside of the closure body
main.rs(301, 48): borrow is only valid in the closure body
No quick fixes available
```
@PitaJ
this is the error

Comment: ```
    let mut res_arr_str = vec![""; s.len()]; // 1
    let mut res_arr_char = vec![' '; s.len()]; //2
    let mut res_arr_string = vec!["".to_string(); s.len()]; // 3
    s.char_indices().for_each(move |(index, ch)| {
        let letter = ch.to_string().as_str();
        let idx = indices[index] as usize;
        res_arr_str[idx] = letter;
    });
    res_arr_char.into_iter().collect()
```
before i think the error borrow is refer to res_arr_str,when write like this i understand the error meaning,thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplified:

```rust
pub fn restore_string(s: String) {
    let mut res_arr_str = vec![""; s.len()];
    s.char_indices().for_each(|(index, ch)| {
        res_arr_str[index] = &ch.to_string();
    });
}
```

Essentially the problem is that `ch.to_string()` creates a new `String`, the lifetime of which only last until the end of the closure body. That is, it will be dropped (destructed, deallocated) when the closure returns. Since the `String` no longer exists outside the closure, storing a reference to the temporary `String` is not allowed, or the reference would be a dangling pointer.